# Display nothing when there is internet connection with react-native-offline

Tags: react-native, error-handling, components

I am using the react-native-offline module. My intention is to display some error when there is no connection. I am using withNetworkConnectivity to display some red text when the internet is off. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { withNetworkConnectivity } from 'react-native-offline';

const ConnectionStatus = ({ isConnected }) => (
  <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{isConnected ? '' : 'You are offline. Make sure your device is connected'}</Text>
  </View>
);

const styles = {
  viewStyle: {
    height: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 0.1
  },
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: 20,
  }
};

export default withNetworkConnectivity()(ConnectionStatus);
```

The problem however is that even when there is internet the space represented by the top View tag is still present. How do I make sure that my component only takes up space when there is not connection ?

Comment: did my suggestion work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to optionally render your text component.

```
const renderText = () => {
    if (!isConnected) { 
        return <Text> Your error Text </Text>;
    }
};

const ConnectionStatus = ({ isConnected }) => (
  <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
    {renderText()}
  </View>
);
```